# DIVI (CSS) - Making modules responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I've finished a layout for the website I'm designing using DIVI and it looked perfect on my 1280x800 laptop resolution, but when I tried to display it on the bigger resolution (in this case 1920x1080) a lot of the elements (mainly the ones with left or right margins/paddings) were out of place. I've tried using percentages instead of pixels as my margin/padding values, but gave the same result.

What would be the best practice in going about designing responsive CSS layouts? Should I define fixed values for width of the containers? Will that solve the issues?

Should I focus on media queries? Define values for each resolution? Then again, there's the issue of resizing the window which again would make the whole media query solution obsolete. What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

RWD (Responsive Web Design) is an argument too broad to give you a single answer. Personally I love building my own web pages from scratch, without any page builder or something like that, and this's the tip I give you: first, try to build your own web pages by hand!

Three guidelines I can give you to build a responsive website are:

- Use percentage values, no fixed values;
- Use media queries;
- Use the `display: flex` property to adapt the layout of webpages when the screen width changes;

With these advices I think you can build easily your responsive web pages.
There are many other factors to worry about: search, learn and get your hands dirty with code!